# Error running "python examples/simulate.py ring"

Tags: flow-project

When I run `sumo --version` after running `scripts/setup_sumo_osx.sh` it gives me the error:

> dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/proj/lib/libproj.15.dylib.
>
> Referenced from: /Users/marsalis/sumo_binaries/bin/sumo
>
> Reason: image not found

This is because in /proj library folder "libproj.15.dylib" is actually "libproj.19.dylib", so this SUMO version seems to be dependent on an older version of proj. Same happens with gdal after I fixed this issue. My temporary solution was to create a symbolic link that uses calls "libproj.19.dylib" whenever SUMO needs "libproj.15.dylib"; however, this is not sufficient.

Now I have another issue. I can't run "python examples/simulate.py ring". When I use a python debugger, it says that a symbol isn't found inside what should be "libproj.15.dylib" or "/usr/local/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.20.dylib". Thus, I'm guessing that there's a bigger issue with Flow's SUMO version and the other dependencies.

Is it possible to use the latest SUMO version for Flow somehow? I have a feeling this would solve my issue. If not, is there another solution I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Running `scripts/setup_sumo_osx.sh` installs an older SUMO version to your computer. It seemed like this was the cause to my error. Thus, I reinstalled both x-quartz and SUMO (using brew) to upgrade SUMO to the latest version. This worked for me. Now the example runs.